# Snowflake SQL: trying to calculate time difference between subsets of subsequent rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some data like the following in a Snowflake database

| DEVICE_SERIAL | REASON_CODE | VERSION | MESSAGE_CREATED_AT | NEXT_REASON_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BA1254862158 | 1 | 4 | 2022-06-23 02:06:03 | 4 |
| BA1254862158 | 4 | 4 | 2022-06-23 02:07:07 | 1 |
| BA1110001111 | 1 | 5 | 2022-06-16 16:19:04 | 4 |
| BA1110001111 | 4 | 5 | 2022-06-16 17:43:04 | 1 |
| BA1110001111 | 5 | 5 | 2022-06-20 14:37:45 | 4 |
| BA1110001111 | 4 | 5 | 2022-06-20 17:31:12 | 1 |

that's the result of a previous query. I'm trying to get the difference between `message_created_at` timestamps where the `device_serial` is the same between subsequent rows, and the first row (of the pair for the difference) has `reason_code` of `1` or `5`, and the second row of the pair has `reason_code` `4`.

For this example, my desired output would be

| DEVICE_SERIAL | VERSION | DELTA_SECONDS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BA1254862158 | 4 | 64 |
| BA1110001111 | 5 | 5040 |
| BA1110001111 | 5 | 10407 |

It's easy to calculate the time difference between every pair of rows (just lead or lag + datediff). But I'm not sure how to structure a query to select only the desired rows so that I can get a datediff between them, without calculating spurious datediffs.

My ultimate goal is to see how these datediffs change between `version`s. I am but a lowly C programmer, my SQL-fu is weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        count(case when reason_code in (1, 5) then 1 end)
            over (partition by device_serial order by message_created_at) as grp
        /* or alternately bracket by the end code */
        -- count(case when reason_code = 4 then 1 end)
            -- over (partition by device_serial order by message_created_at desc) as grp

    from T
)
select device_serial, min(version) as version,
    datediff(second, min(message_created_at), max(message_created_at)) as delta_seconds
from data
group by device_serial, grp
```